# YouTube Analytics returns "Request is missing required authentication credential. "

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, youtube-analytics-api

I want to use YouTube Analytics to crawl my video's some data.

partial code is

```
scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.download',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.third-party-link.creator',
        ]

client_secrets_file = 'client_secret_xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube_analytics = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtubeAnalytics', 'v2', credentials = credentials)

def main_data(video_id):
    request_analytics = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        startDate = '%d-%02d-01' % (year, month),
        endDate = '%d-%02d-%d' % (year, month, day),
        ids = 'video==%s' % video_id,
        dimensions = 'day', 
        metrics = 'views',
    )
    response = request_analytics.execute()['rows']
```

It returns

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?startDate=2022-06-01&endDate=2022-06-30&ids=video%3D%3Dj1npnTro9vY&dimensions=day&metrics=views&alt=json returned "An internal error has occurred.". Details: "[{'message': 'An internal error has occurred.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'internalError'}]">

Then I went to the website and the error response it gave was

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

What part might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should try following the official sample https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/code_samples/python  Remember this code is designed for an installed app if your hosting it your going to have issues.

Comment: But I copied the code it returns "invalid syntax" @DaImTo